# Does session.save() do an immediate insert?

Tags: java, hibernate

...or does it wait until the associated transaction is committed?

I'm using an HQL query in a loop like this:

```
tx.begin()
for(...)
{
    session.getNamedQuery(...).list()
    ...
    session.save(new MyEntity())
}
tx.commit()
```

The named query needs to be able to see the entities that were added with the save call.  Will it work that way?

Comment: By far the easiest way to find out is to try if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the flush mode of the session.
You can also manually flush it with `session.flush()`

The flush mode can be set in multiple ways - `session.setFlushMode(..)`, `entityManager.setFlushMode(..)`, or via xml configuration (`org.hibernate.FlushMode`).

The default value is `AUTO`:

> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, if it doesn't, then call

```
session.flush()
```

to send the SQL to the DB.  Regardless, it won't be committed until the call to

```
tx.commit()
```